# Importing the 'val' package in Scala source

Tags: scala

Create a Java package named 'val' and put a class in it and try to import it in a Scala program. scalac will fail with the following error message:

```
[scalac] /tmp/Hello.scala:6: error: identifier expected but 'val' found.
[scalac] import net.slimweb.ann.val.NotEmpty
[scalac]                        ^
[scalac] one error found
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14):

```
import net.slimweb.ann.`val`.NotEmpty
```

Backquotes can be used to escape symbols:

```
scala> val `val` = 1
val: Int = 1

scala> class `val`
defined class val
```

Except for using them to define symbols with reserved names, or call legacy java code that has keywords as methods (e.g., a method named with), they can also be used for symbols with spaces in them or otherwise weird characters

Comment: @prokoba -- IttayD's answer will certainly work, but it's a much better choice to *rename* your package if you can.  Other suggested names: `import`, `def`, and `class`.  \x6a\x6b!